# Can prolonged neural adaptation lead to HPPD?

Tags: neuroscience, perception, abnormal-psychology, optical-illusion

The human brain adapts to a constant stimulus of our neural system. For instance, if we ride a train and look out of the window for a long time and the train stops, we have the feeling of slowly moving backwards.

There are other, more extreme stimulus like a neave strobe as shown in this picture:

[image: Neave Strobe]

This particular animated image produces a rapid neural adaption causing us to see things moving for about 10 seconds. I have also observed that [binaural beats](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binaural_beats) cause minor ear ringing symptoms if listened to for a longer period of time.

The burning question here is: **Can prolonged stimulus to such images or sounds cause [Hallucinogen persisting perception disorder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hallucinogen_persisting_perception_disorder)**?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.  This disorder requires the sufferer to have used hallucinogenic substances in the past:

> Previous use of hallucinogens by the person is necessary, but not sufficient, for diagnosis of HPPD. For an individual to be diagnosed with HPPD, the symptoms cannot be due to another medical condition.

from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hallucinogen_persisting_perception_disorder) following the DSM-IV criteria reproduced [here](http://behavenet.com/hallucinogen-persisting-perception-disorder).

> A. The reexperiencing, following cessation of use of a hallucinogen, of one or more of the perceptual symptoms that were experienced while intoxicated with the hallucinogen (e.g., geometric hallucinations, false perceptions of movement in the peripheral visual fields, flashes of color, intensified colors, trails of images of moving objects, positive afterimages, halos around objects, macropsia, and micropsia).